# What is the difference between "#if Foo - 0 == 0" and "#if defined(Foo) && Foo == 0"?

Tags: c++, c, qt, c-preprocessor

Find this in the [qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Coding-Conventions).
What is the difference between

```
#if defined(Foo) && Foo ==  0
```

and

```
#if Foo - 0 ==  0
```

As far as I understand the latter also will be false if Foo is undefined? Where can I read about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If `Foo` is undefined, then the latter will translate to

```
#if 0 - 0 == 0
```

which is *true*, not false. Remember that under `#if` all undefined identifiers are replaced with literal `0` (once all `defined()` operators are evaluated, of course). That applies even to preprocessing tokens that match language keywords. In C language all keywords are replaced with `0` in this context. In C++ keywords `true` and `false` are exempt from replacement, while all other keywords are replaced.

(BTW, that means that in C `true` will be quietly replaced with `0` if `<stdbool.h>` is not included, and with `1` if `<stdbool.h>` is included.)

Meanwhile

```
#if defined(Foo) && Foo == 0
```

is false when `Foo` is undefined. So, here's your difference.

The Qt documentation does indeed seem to suggest that the former is the same as the latter. I don't know why they do that, since they are certainly not equivalent. It appears to be an error in Qt docs.

Comment: So there is a mistake in Qt docs! 'cos from their explanation it come out that those two are equal

Comment: +1 for `all undefined identifiers are replaced with literal 0`

Comment: @billz and AndreyT can you share with me some links or advice articles about macros in C++? Because what I've found about them is just their list and brief description, but I certainly didn't read anywhere things like "all undefined identifiers are replaced with literal 0".

Comment: Here's the actual rule in the Standard: "After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for `true` and `false`, are replaced with the pp-number `0`, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token." section 16.1p4

Comment: ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++ standard) §16.1 Conditional inclusion says: _¶4 Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling
constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the defined unary operator),
just as in normal text. [...] After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator
have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for true and false, are replaced
with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token._

Answer (score 1):

Difference between Foo == 0 and Foo - 0 ==  0 is that in the former, Foo must be defined with a value:

```
#define Foo 0
```

and cannot be:

```
#define Foo  //  Foo == 0 would give an error, cannot evaluate Foo
```

While in the case of Foo - 0 ==  0, Foo can be defined without a value

So:

```
#if defined(Foo) && Foo ==  0
```

Means Foo defined and it has a value (of 0 in this case).

and:

```
#if Foo - 0 ==  0
```

Means Foo is either defined with 0 or defined without a value, but since it doesn't have the defined(Foo) like in the first case, Foo undefined would apply as well.